# Autoload path and STI inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models `User` and `Manager`. I use STI to inherit `Manager` from `User` model.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

**custom_lib/models/manager.rb**

```
class Manager < User

end
```

I have added the custom models to load path as follows:

**config/environment.rb**

```
config.autoload_path += File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "custom_lib", "models")
```

Every thing works as expected in development mode. In the production mode I get the following error:

```
The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: Manager
```

For some reason rails is not loading the inherited classes.

To work around this issue I explicitly require the classes in an initializer.

**config/initializers/custom_models.rb**

```
Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "custom_lib", "models", "*.rb")].each do |file_name|
  require(File.join(File.dirname(file_name), File.basename(file_name, ".rb")))
end
```

I prefer to use `autoload_path`. I am wondering if anybody else has seen this behavior.

I am on Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.9, Ubuntu

**Edit 1**

I am aware that everything works if all the models are residing in `app/models` directory. In my application generated models are residing in custom location, hence this requirement.

Comment: have you tried a `require` or `require_relative` statement within your custom_lib?

Comment: take a look at the pre-loading code and see if it helps https://gist.github.com/chrisbloom7/1713398

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `manager.rb` file in your `app/models` directory where your `user.rb` file is. That's where rails looks for models.  There's no benefit to hiding the manager model in a different directory.

Once you do this, you can also get rid of mucking with the load path.

Comment: This is not a relevant answer. My application is loading certain third party models. I can't dictate their location.